# How can I fix accessibility warning about content label?

Tags: flutter, accessibility

I'm very new to developing apps, I was able to develop my first app but, got problem with "flutter build apk", as I couldn't upload my app apk to the store because it wasn't made for 64-bits. Then I run "flutter build appbundle", it generated an .aab file, which I could upload to google play, but when I downloaded and installed it, it only shows a white screen when openned. I checked google play console report and it shows me it's an accessibility issue about content label. Unfortunately I couldn't find any topic about the same problem. Does any of you guys know something related or have any idea on how to fix it? thanks in advance for your help, there is a print screen on the link below.

[google play console report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/193ob.png)

Answer (score -9, accepted):

`Edit/Update:` Google has released Flutter 1.7.8+hotfix.3 in stable channel, which makes easy to build app for release.

Now you have two options to build :

1. App bundle (preferred)
2. APK

> Generating App Bundle

Run   `flutter build appbundle`

This will create `<app dir>/build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab` 

T app bundle contains your Dart code and the Flutter runtime compiled for `armeabi-v7a (32-bit)` and `arm64-v8a (64-bit)`.

Now you can upload this app bundle to google play.

> Build an APK

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

This command results in two APK files:

```
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
```

Removing the --split-per-abi flag results in a fat APK that contains your code compiled for all the target ABIs. Such APKs are larger in size than their split counterparts, causing the user to download native binaries that are not applicable to their device’s architecture.

> Only for Older Version of Flutter

You need to build two apk and upload it together. one for 32 and another for 64 bit.

I am on flutter v1.5.4-hotfix.2

First run `flutter build apk --release` and upload the apk file

Then increase the version and build number in pubspec.yml file and run

```
flutter build apk --release --target-platform=android-arm64
```

Upload this new apk and start rollout.

Comment: What a totally unrelated answer! This question is talking about google play store console's warning about accessibility issue. It seems that we need to add description to image somehow, to help visually impaired people so they can use screen reader feature to know what is the image about.